# Update product price every 30sec in magento

Tags: magento, product

I have to update product prices every 30sec which is like http://www.bullionbypost.co.uk/ and http://www.coininvestdirect.com/en/. i am just confused how they did in above sites. i am new to magento. please any body sugguest me

Thanks

Comment: Neither of those sites appear to be based on Magento.

Comment: you can use cron, http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, using Magento CRON is not possible for sub-one-minute scheduling; so if 30 second updates are critical you're going to have to use another method - or reconsider using Magento. I would suggest using AJAX to update the pricing on the product page and using a webservice to grab the price at the time of the product add. You'll have to leverage observers to update the price on add.

If you are going to use custom pricing for products you won't be able to take advantage of the pricing index - and you'll have to use the `setCustomPrice` and `setIsSuperMode` methods on the product quote item - again, use observers for this. See the following two stack articles for more details - they do work in CE 1.6, 1.7 and EE 1.10, 1.11.

[Programmatically add product to cart with price change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104482/programmatically-add-product-to-cart-with-price-change)

[Magento custom price rules for product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806136/magento-custom-price-rules-for-product)